# I found very strange http_requests_total behavior with prometheus and grafana

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, metrics, fastapi

my fastapi application server metrics have been measured with prometheus.

I have one thing that I can't explain.
that is sometimes http_requests_total value decreases.

As far as I know, the value is accumulated, so there is no possibility that the value can change other than increasing or maintaining the value.

I used the basic fast API with 3 workers gunicorn and a total of 3 Pods are maintained.

Also, the query was very simple one as the below.

```
http_requests_total{job=~"news-collector-.*"}
```

metrics are collected from all 3 pods.

Siege was used for the test and it wasn't a very burdensome stress.

There is no way to explain the figure.
Someone please help me.

[image]

Comment: share query from dashboard that this graph corresponds to. My guess is that `rate(..` is applied